# Why can't I create a New Color

Tags: java, android-studio

When I try to create a color using the RGB values I get a message saying "Color() in Color cannot be applied to:" and then its says "Expected parameter:" and "Actual Arguments:"

```
import android.graphics.Color;

Color myColor = new Color (0,0,0);
```

When I try to run the program it says:

```
error: constructor Color in class Color cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: int,int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: Because that's not what the `Color` class expects in its constructor, as per the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#Color() Which is pretty much the same thing the error message says.

Comment: Short answer - try one of the static `valueOf` methods, instead of the constructor.

Comment: Are you certain you actually need a `Color` instance? You generally don't create instances of the `Color` class. Most colors are simple `int` values. The `Color` class is mostly just a bunch of static methods to manipulate those. If you want to create an `int` color value from RGB values, use the [`Color.rgb()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#rgb(int,%20int,%20int)) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to say it's

```
//Color black
Color myColor = Color.valueOf(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
```

according to @esqew's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#valueOf(float,%2520float,%2520float)). Remember that values are in the range [0,1], not [0,255]

Alternatively, as @DaveNewton suggested, we can use either of the following:

```
//Color white
Color myColor = Color.valueOf(Color.rgb(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f));//floats, [0,1]
Color myColor = Color.valueOf(Color.rgb(255,255,255));//ints, [0,255]
```

These methods are documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#rgb(float,%2520float,%2520float)), [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#rgb(int,%2520int,%2520int)), and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#valueOf(int)).

Comment: Or `rgb` to use `int`s.